# RTSP IP camera Hikvision

Tags: golang, ip, камера

Пробую с IP камеры видеонаблюдения Hikvision записать видео в файл

```go
package main

import (
    "github.com/geoirb/video/pkg/joy4/av/avutil"
    "github.com/geoirb/video/pkg/joy4/format"
)

func init() {
    format.RegisterAll()
}

func main() {
    in, _ := avutil.Open("rtsp://user:admin@192.168.0.64:554/ISAPI/Streaming/Channels/101")
    out, _ := avutil.Create("./out.mp4")

    streams, _ := in.Streams()
    if err := out.WriteHeader(streams); err != nil {
        return
    }

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        pkt, err := in.ReadPacket()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        out.WritePacket(pkt)
    }
    if err := out.WriteTrailer(); err != nil {
        return
    }

    out.Close()
    in.Close()
}
```

Но на `pkt, err := in.ReadPacket()` код виснит, хотя с другими камерами все отлично работает, до этого момента код работает отличною, параметры камеры
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предположение от балды: возможно видеопоток идёт через UDP и он режется каким-нибудь фаерволом или типа того? Я бы попробовал добавить опцию `-rtsp_transport tcp` но не знаю как это сделать через golang

Comment: Да и в принципе можно для теста попробовать использовать команду ffmpeg, чтобы выяснить, в программе ли причина или в чём-то другом `ffmpeg -i "rtsp://user:admin@192.168.0.64:554/ISAPI/Streaming/Channels/101" -c copy out.mp4`

Comment: Убедитесь, что кроме вас поток не читает никто.  Есть такая фишка у некоторых камер: ограничение числа клиентов.  Когда 2, когда и вовсе 1.

Comment: у меня из питона (OpenCV) на этих камерах прекрасно забирает поток по rtsp. количество коннектов сильно зависит от потока 101(основной) или 102(суб поток) и от модели камеры, некоторые и 8мь потоков могут отдать, а некоторые на 3м основном уже задыхаются. В качестве теста можешь попробовать выключить авторизацию RTSP в настройках камеры ( по умолчанию там стоит дайджест в новых / бейсик в старых) возможно твоя библиотека просто не может правильно пройти авторизацию, после нескольких  попыток камера радостно тебя заблокирует до ребута / сброса по питанию.

Comment: P.S. для тестирования строки подключения можно юзать vlc. если и в влц не сработает строка подключения значит что-то не так настроено в камере, либо юзера заблокировала "защита от нелегального входа"  tm.